# How to plot a graph of Probability density function using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data set

[link to dataset](http://www.sendspace.pl/file/982d6a52dd9aec0af9228f4)

I want to plot a graph showing the Probability density function for the variable quality of the division on the type of wine.

I try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
db <- dbeta(wines$quality, 1, 1)
qplot(wines$quality, db, geom="line")
```

but it plot flat line.

ok, i think my code don't have any sens. I want to do somethink lie that: 
[Example](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Probability%20density%20function&client=firefox-a&hs=5jo&rls=org.mozilla%3apl%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=sUKrUbGCNYel4ASgoYHoCg&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAQ&biw=946&bih=927#facrc=_&imgrc=g6Fs-zcHZ6K-_M%3a;AZGIyKDhdBNcqM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.engineeredsoftware.com%252Fnasa%252Fimages%252Fimage101.gif;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.engineeredsoftware.com%252Fnasa%252Fnormal.htm;455;347)
x-quality of wines(dry,semi-dry....)

What can I do?

Comment: how can I get the data set? it seems to be an image. Edit and add, `dput(wines)`

Comment: I don't understand. You want output of dput(wines)?

Comment: The link you put it's perfect thanks. I thought the data frame was not so big, so `dput` was feasible...

Comment: It plots a horizontal line because all `db` values are zero. Try a different distribution.

Comment: -1 please read up a little on ggplot2 before asking here, and try to post _minimal_ reproducible examples (why would we have to download data from some website?)

Comment: [examples of my dataset](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/beztytuujcdj.png/)

Comment: As Roland points out the distribution you're using doesn't make sense for your data.  The beta only takes values between 0 and 1 and your data appears to all be above 1.  One of the first steps to checking why you aren't getting the plot you want is to check if the data you're giving to the plotting function is correct.  In this case it apparently wasn't what you expected.

Comment: Also - a beta with parameters 1 and 1 will give a uniform distribution so if anything you should have been expecting a flat line as the outcome...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ggplot(wines) + geom_density(aes(quality))
```

EDIT:

I see your point, but probably you just need to rescale the y values (am I correct?)
so is not this what you're after? **changed the image**

```
ggplot(wines[-4381,]) + geom_density(aes(x=quality)) +
  facet_wrap(~sweetnes)
```

[image]

or all in one with different `fill`

```
ggplot(wines) + geom_density(aes(x=quality, fill=sweetnes))
```

[image]

Comment: oh, i want to plot a graph showing Probability density function, somehow i miss one word in my post. I very sorry for that.

Comment: in fact it is what i'm looking for, but i want do it for every kind of wines(dry,semi-dry....)

Comment: @user1972123 now it should be fine. And if you want to remove the "sweet" level from  the first image just remove the single row there is in the data frame for `sweetness=="sweet"` and it'll plot only three charts

Comment: Wait - this is what the data looks like?  I don't think a density plot is the best thing to be making when you want to visualize data that takes only a small number of integer values...

Comment: @Dason possibly... e.g. in this **specific** case I would have used a bar chart. Just because in my "environment" it would be seen as more professional... and easier to be understood by senior managers.